# How can I find which exception(s) maybe raised by RAVENDB methods?

Tags: exception, ravendb, ravendb4

I’m newbie to RAVENDB. How can I find which exception(s) maybe raised by RAVENDB methods? I’ve searched the online documentation and “Inside RAVENDB Book” without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the [`RavenException`](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v4.0/src/Raven.Client/Exceptions/RavenException.cs) base class.

Here you can found all of the possible exceptions: 
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/v4.0/src/Raven.Client/Exceptions

Comment: Thank you Fitzchak for the link. Let me explain what I realy want to know by using an example. When i open a session there are some possible exceptions. Is there any way to find all possible exceptions?

Comment: No, there is no list of possible exceptions for each method. The number of errors is too big to detail all of them.